# Next.jsに追加したgoogle analyticsの gtag.jsをTypeScriptにして型を導入したい。

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-analytics

下記のブログを参考にNext.jsで作成したブログにgoogle analyticsを導入したのですが、gtag.jsをTypeScriptに変換する所で躓いています。

[Next.jsでGoogle Analyticsを使えるようにする](https://panda-program.com/posts/nextjs-google-analytics/#GA%E3%82%A4%E3%83%99%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E7%99%BA%E7%81%AB%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

google analyticsの型を [@types/google.analytics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google.analytics) `npm install --save @types/google.analytics`しました。 それを `import` したいのですが上手く呼び出せません。

参考サイトでは下記のように呼び出しています。
しかし、参考サイトでは型を呼び出すパス以前に `src/hooks/usePageView.js` というファイルを生成しておりルートディレクトリにsrcフォルダがあります。当然srcフォルダにTypesというフォルダがないので `import` しようがないのですが、どのようにしてインストールした google analyticsの型を `import` したら良いのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

```
import { Event } from 'src/Types/GoogleAnalytics/Event'

export const event = ({action, category, label}: Event) => {
  if (!existsGaId) {
    return
  }

  window.gtag('event', action, {
    event_category: category,
    event_label: JSON.stringify(label)
  })
}
```

#### 追記

[@types パッケージ (DefinitelyTyped)](https://typescript-jp.gitbook.io/deep-dive/type-system/types) を参考に下記のコードでimportしてみたのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。

**試したコード:**

```
import { Event } from "google.analytics";
```

**エラー:**

```
node_modules/@types/google.analytics/index.d.ts' is not a module
```

Comment: `> @types/google.analyticsという型定義があります。しかし、型定義ではgaというメソッドにしか対応しておらず、gtagという書き方は存在しないのです。` 参考サイトを読む限り、そもそも `@types/google.analytics` は使用せずに自分で型を定義(作成)して使っているようですが…。なので記事に書かれている `export type Event = ContactEvent | ClickEvent` (記事の `Event.ts` の内容すべて) をどこか自分の好きなファイルに記述して使用すればよいと思いました。

Comment: そうなんですね。記事を読み間違えてますね。ありがとうございます。